# How i can create a GUI for SharpDX

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, directx, sharpdx

I am work with Sharpdx/C# - i'm wondering how Unity/UnrealEngine/CryEngine create their GUI for the Editor.

After some research i find "D3Dsurface" to work with WPF. But the Performance/FPS should be bad.

I cant believe all the engines (http://xenko.com - SharpDX engine) do their own GUI from scratch.

I tried to create a second Winform, it works but not the right approach for me.

best regards alex!

Answer (score 0):

Xenko use [this](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) and so do I, it looks really good

Telerik windows forms are really good as they can be themed and tweaked to how you like.

Xenko like my self use the dark Visual Studio theme.

They have a free trial so u can get you feet wet before you go and drop cash on it, they also have a forum so you can ask for help and a few times I have seen them go out of there way to help.

Once you get your hands on the Dev pack you can modify the source and all sorts of cool stuff.

I have tried a few other windows forms controls but I settled on Telerik a few years ago and haven't looked back.

All in all I give them a 10/10 and they have some really nice CPU\RAM profiling tools.